# Ruby on Rails does not find routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I set up a Rails project, and `http://dev.xxx.com/public/` resolved to `/home/xxx/public_html/xxx/public/index.html`

When I try to access a controller, I keep getting 404s.

For instance, `pages_controller.rb`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

When accessing `http://dev.xxx.com/PagesController`, I get the error:

```
File does not exist:  /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/rails_apps/belldev/PagesController
```

When accessing `http//dev.xxx.com/xxx/rails_apps/belldev/app/controllers/pages_controller`, I get the error:

```
File does not exist: /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/rails_apps/belldev/xxx
```

Please enlighten me as to what am I doing wrong, here.

Comment: OK, tried this:  http://dev.xxx.com/pages => File does not exist: /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/rails_apps/belldev/pages

Comment: routes.rb   `xxx::Application.routes.draw do

  #Pages controller
  get "pages/index"
  get "pages/help",  as: :help
  get "pages/browse", as: :browse
  
  root to: "pages#index"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your routing is setup correctly, your address should be `http://dev.xxx.com/pages/` not `http://dev.xxx.com/PagesController/`

Comment: tried http://dev.xxx.com/pages/ and still got "File does not exist: /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/rails_apps/belldev/pages" ... so somehow, it isn't going into belldev/app/controllers/" ??

Comment: Could you post your routes.rb file? If that's it in your comment above, could you edit your original post to include it?

Also, what's your file tree look like starting at your application root?